# Automatic dependency resolution using GNU Makefile

Tags: gcc, g++, makefile, gnu

I'm writing a piece of software that utilizes a Makefile for compilation, originally I had a rule setup for each file however this proved to be too cumbersome whenever I added a new file. To try and automate the process I did some research and learnt that GCC/G++ can automatically build Makefile rules with the -M flag.

There are many examples of this being done with a simple directory structure however my ideal directory structure looks like this:

```
src/ 
    kernel.hpp kernel.cpp
    Types/
          String.cpp
          String.hpp
    Drivers/IO-Ports/
          CMOS.cpp
          CMOS.hpp
    ...

build/
    DEPS/
        kernel.d
        Types/String.d
        ...
    OBJ/
        kernel.o
        Types/String.o
        ...
```

My current Makefile:

```
CCHOME=/home/dan/opt/cross/bin
CC=@$(CCHOME)/i586-elf-g++
CFLAGS=-ffreestanding -O2 -Wextra -Wall -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti

KernelName=CPlusKern
QEMU=qemu-system-x86_64 -monitor stdio

SrcDIR=src
SourceDIRS:=$(shell find $(SrcDIR) -type d)
SrcFILES=$(shell find $(SrcDIR) -type f -name *.cpp)
HdrFILES=$(shell find $(SrcDIR) -type f -name *.hpp)

DepDIR=$(BuildDIR)/DEPS
DepFILES0=$(subst $(SrcDIR), $(DepDIR),$(SrcFILES))
DepFILES=$(subst .cpp,.d,$(DepFILES0))

ObjDIR=$(BuildDIR)/OBJ
ObjDIRS=$(subst $(SrcDIR),$(ObjDIR),$(SourceDIRS))
ObjFILES0=$(subst $(SrcDIR), $(ObjDIR),$(SrcFILES))
ObjFILES=$(subst .cpp,.o,$(ObjFILES0))

BuildDIR=build
BuildDIRS=$(BuildDIR) $(ObjDIR) $(DepDIR)


all: assemble compile run
image: assemble compile build-image run-image

debug:
    @echo "BuildDIRS: " $(BuildDIRS)
    @echo "DepFiles: " $(DepFILES)
    @echo "SrcFiles: " $(SrcFILES)
    @echo "ObjFiles: " $(ObjFILES)

./src/kernel.o: ./src/kernel.cpp
    @echo $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF $< -o $(subst $(SrcDIR), $(ObjDIR),$@)

./src/kernel.cpp:

dir:
    @echo "Making Build Dirs..."
    @-mkdir -p $(BuildDIRS)

compile: dir $(ObjFILES)
#   @echo "Compiling Source Files: " $(SrcFILES)

assemble: dir boot.o
    @echo "Assembling Core Files..."

boot.o: $(SrcDIR)/boot.s
    @$(CCHOME)/i586-elf-as $(SrcDIR)/boot.s -o $(ObjDIR)/boot.o

build: %.o
    echo "Building Kernel Binary..."
    @$(CC) -T linker.ld -o $(KernelName).bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib $(SrcFILES)-lgcc

build-image: build
    @echo "Building Kernel Image..."
    @cp $(KernelName).bin isodir/boot/$(KernelName).bin
    @Scripts/MakeGrub.sh $(KernelName) isodir/boot/grub
    grub-mkrescue -o $(KernelName).iso isodir

%.o: %.cpp Makefile
    @echo "Building Object $@"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF $(subst $(SrcDIR),$(DepDIR),$@) -o $(subst $(SrcDIR), $(ObjDIR),$@)

run:
    @echo "Starting QEMU"
    @$(QEMU) -kernel $(KernelName).bin

run-image:
    @echo "Starting QEMU"
    @$(QEMU) -bios OVMF.fd -cdrom $(KernelName).iso

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning Build Directories..."
    -@rm -R $(BuildDIR) ./isodir
    -@$(RM) $(KernelName).bin $(KernelName).iso
```

I thought this might do the trick however make throws an error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `build/OBJ/VGA.o', needed by `compile'. Stop.
```

I can't determine how to make the rule:

```
%.o: %.cpp Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -MF $(subst $(SrcDIR),$(DepDIR),$@) -o $(subst $(SrcDIR), $(ObjDIR),$@)
```

apply to every .cpp file. As far as I know wildcards cannot be used in rule definitions.

I'm not sure if this helps but the path/name of each source file is stored in the $(SrcFILES) variable.

Just to clarify, here is an expanded version of the above rule:

```
/home/dan/opt/cross/bin/i586-elf-g++ -ffreestanding -O2 -Wextra -Wall -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -MMD -MP -MF src/kernel.cpp -o build/OBJ/kernel.o
```

And the generated dependency file for this instance:

```
kernel.o: src/kernel.cpp src/kernel.hpp src/Globals.hpp \
 src/VGATerminal.hpp src/Types/String.hpp src/Types/../Globals.hpp \
 src/VGA.hpp src/IO/Read.hpp src/IO/Write.hpp \
 src/Drivers/IO-Ports/CMOS.hpp src/Drivers/IO-Ports/../../IO/Read.hpp \
 src/Drivers/IO-Ports/../../IO/Write.hpp
```

This is my first post here so feedback on my question is appreciated :)

Hopefully I can get this out of the way and get back to developing my code.

EDIT:
The rule provided by @Beta worked without a problem, All of my Object files successfully build and are output in the right place. This rule even picked up `build/OBJ/Drivers/IO-Ports/CMOS.o` and `build/OBJ/Drivers/PS2.o`.

So now I can happily build all of the Objects individually if I pass the filename however I think I still need dependency resolution so that I don't have to write  a rule for each file.

Answer (score 0):

This may take a few iterations.

The first problem is that you have a target, `build/OBJ/VGA.o` and no corresponding rule. The rule

```
%.o: %.cpp Makefile
    ...
```

doesn't fit; it can build `build/OBJ/VGA.o` from `build/OBJ/VGA.cpp`, but there's no such source file.

So for a first step, if the source file is `src/whatever/VGA.cpp`, try this rule:

```
build/OBJ/%.o: src/whatever/%.cpp
    ...
```

and tell us the result.

**EDIT:**

Good, now try this:

```
build/OBJ/%.o: src/%.cpp
    ...
```

Comment: I edited my post to include the part-solution, hopefully that was the right thing to do.


I'm glad to see that the rule worked however I find it confusing that the rule works on files in the build/OBJ directory **and** all of it's subfolders. If % works as a wildcard why didn't **every** %.o file get picked up in my previous rule?